# How do I add a line-break to a multiple assignment statement?

Tags: python, line-breaks

In the following Python example:

```
a1,  a2,  ..., a30,
a31, a32, ..., a60 = get_values()
```

I can't insert a line-break after the variable `a30` because if I do that the syntax is not correct. But then I do not know how I could correctly write code lines with any possible large length I might think of.

Comment: you can use ` \` space backslash if you want to divide a statement into two lines

Comment: Are you trying to assign 60 variables with a statement? I recommend using a list instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could do it eventually by adding brackets as follows:

```
(a1, a2, ................a30,
a31, a32, ..............a60) = get_values()
```

Comment: As Joe said in comments and his answer, I will re-iterate that ***this is not something you should do***. There is no possible good reason to have 60 variables from one assignment. Those variables should either be a list or a dictionary or any other appropriate structure

Comment: It was just an exagerated example. I wanted to know the grammar and I know it now. Anyway, what is the limit of the maximum amount of variables that would be considered reasonable for my suggested approach?

Comment: There are no written rules. You should generally follow [the Zen](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) and common sense. A code with very long lines or tens of variables assigned at once makes the code very hard to follow and read

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you want to split an assignment statement into two lines.

Here's how to do it.

```
a1,a2,a3,a4, \
a5,a6,a7,a8 = list('abcdefgh')
print (a1, a2, a3, a4,
       a5, a6, a7, a8)
```

The output of this will be:

```
a b c d e f g h
```

If you are going to store 60 variables using an assignment statement, I recommend using a list instead.

```
a = list('abcdefgh')
print (*a)
print (a[2])
```

The output of this will be:

```
a b c d e f g h
c
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo, yes, you are correct. Didn't realize. Removed.